# In(to) a road/path or On(to) a road/path?

Tags: prepositions, difference

On the topic of giving directions, I'm not sure whether I should suggest someone to "turn *into* the right lane / the driveway / Long Road" or "turn *onto* the right lane / the driveway / Long Road". The answers to this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56828/into-onto-a-curve-path-road/70678#70678) seem to suggest that as you drive **on** the surfaces of roads, you should be turning **onto** them. But an example from the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says otherwise:

"She cycled up the street and turned **into** Long Road."

And so does a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enVN720VN720&espv=2&q=turn%20left%20into%20or%20turn%20left%20onto&oq=turn%20left%20into%20or%20turn%20left%20onto&gs_l=serp.3...113516.117640.0.117769.10.10.0.0.0.0.113.958.6j4.10.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.0.0.Em-czueJ5TA). Notice there are instances of "turning left into either lane", "turning into a driveway", "turning left into a multi-lane road" among the results.

A user at [forum.wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-you-turn-onto-on-to-into-in-to-a-street.2309782/) suggests that whether you drive in or on a road/path, it could depends on the particular types of roads wherein "the concept of an inside would be apparent".

Is that wordreference user right? If so, what exactly are the types of roads that give you such a concept of "an inside"? When do you turn **into** a road? When do you turn **onto** it?

Answer (score 1):

In AmE:

We turn **onto** a road.

We drive **onto** an off-ramp.

We move **into** the exit lane or move **into** the passing lane.

We turn **into** a driveway. If the driveway is on a slope, we can "pull up **onto** the driveway".

We leave the main road and turn **into** a lane (a small, often unpaved, country road) or turn **into** an alley or alleyway.

Comment: What makes a driveway or a lane so different from a road or a ramp? Aren't you supposed to drive **on** them? What am I missing?

Comment: Natural languages evolve over many centuries. Driveways and lanes have been perceived as ways of *ingress* and *egress*.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about giving directions

> onto

usually seems to be used for *named* roads

> Take the second left **onto** Interstate 35 south.
>   At the second, traffic light turn south **onto** Gameskeeper Road.

whereas

> Drive down bout a mile and pull **into** the cul de sac.
>   He drove his car out of the parking lot and **into** Main Street traffic.

Loosely, either seem to be interchangeable.  However, one would not "pull **onto** a cul de sac" since it is a surrounded area.